# Need to setup email notification when system starts and shutdown

Tags: 12.10, startup, shutdown, email, cron

I would like to have the system send me a email notification everrytime the system starts or shuts down.
I am currently running Ubuntu 12.10

I found [this tutorial](http://www.syntaxtechnology.com/2009/06/email-on-shutdown-and-restart/) but I couldn't make it to work.